# Exploring search options for PHP

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, full-text-search

I have innoDB table using numerous foreign keys, but we just want to look up some basic info out of it.

I've done some research but still lost.

1. How can I tell if my host has Sphinx
   installed already?  I don't see it
   as an option for table storage
   method (i.e. innodb, myisam).
2. Zend_Search_Lucene, responsive
       enough for AJAX functionality of
       millions of records?
3. Mirror my
       innoDB with a myisam?  Make every
       innodb transaction end with a write
       to the myisam, then use 1:1 lookups?
       How would I do this automagically? 
       This should make MyISAM
       ACID-compliant and free(er) from
       corruption no?
4. PostgreSQL fulltext
       queries don't even look like SQL to
       me wtf, I don't have time to learn a
       new SQL syntax I need noob options
5. ????????????????????

This is high volume site on a decently-equipped VPS

Thanks very much for any ideas.

Comment: Please be more specific.  Are you looking for fulltext searching?  If so, on a single column?  Multiple columns?  Do you need to support operators, proximity searches, and the like?  Do you have access enough to install 3rd party tools?

Comment: I think I want fulltext search for "title" and "body" fields.  I want whatever the industry standard options are, including sorted by relevancy and a score if possible.  I am weary of MyISAM corruption, as there are many concurrent transactions on this DB.  Yes I can install 3rd party tools.

Comment: Then Sphinx is it, all the way.  I'm upvoting @vartec's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sphinx** is very good choice. Very scalable, [**built-in clustering and sharding**](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#distributed).

Comment: After a minor learning curve, Sphinx has never let me down or left me disappointed - just make sure you get friendly with the docs.

Comment: I'm reading the docs and am confused, is this just a plugin or a new storage table type or what.  Once installed I can just use MyISAM syntax fulltext lookups on innoDB tables?  Also, how do I tell/test if it's already installed, (like from phpMyAdmin, cpanel, or linux shell).

Comment: @Joshua, no, Sphinx indexes existing tables (InnoDB, MyISAM, doesn't matter, you actually provide SQL). Then you do search queries against search engine. It returns IDs of objects from the DB.
This is way more advanced/complicated then just a plugin for MySQL.

Comment: Found a good write-up by IBM if anyone else is looking into this too.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-sphinxsearch/

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very vague on what you're actually wanting to accomplish here but I can tell you to stay away from Zend_Search_Lucene with record counts that high. In my experience (and many others, including Zend Certified Engineers) ZSL's performance on large record-sets is poor at best. Use a tool like Apache Lucene instead if you go that route.